# Is this a CSS bug? Left border not showing up

Tags: html, css

I have the following problem: when I first select one of the two boxes the left border is missing (Google Chrome 36); after I select the other one the left border appears.
JSFIDDLE:

```
 http://jsfiddle.net/emrfcuu7/
```

Observe that immediately after compiling the code - when selecting one of the two boxes the left border is missing; is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,300,400,600,700,800);
.main {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #16A085;
  width: 550px;
  height: 350px;
}

.mainRibbon {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ECF0F1;
  width: 70%;
  height: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.textBoxStyle {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid rgba(26, 188, 156, 0);
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 80%;
  text-indent: 20px;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  line-height: 1.4285;
  -webkit-transition: border-color .25s linear;
  transition: border-color .25s linear;
  margin: 6% 10% 0 10%;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
}

.textBoxStyle:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border-color: rgba(26, 188, 156, 1);
}

.btnLogin {
  background-color: #16A085;
  width: 80%;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin: 6% 10% 0 10%;
  -webkit-transition: background .25s linear;
  transition: background .25s linear;
}

.btnLogin:hover {
  background-color: #1ABC9C;
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
}

.btnLogin>p {
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 1%;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
  font-size: 17px;
  text-align: center;
}

.icon {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.icon>p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}


/*de sters
    .test{
        position:relative;
        background-color:blue;
        width:80%;
        height:30%;
        top:50%;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
      -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
      transform: translateY(-50%);
    }*/
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="icon">
    <p class="text icon">&#61584;</p>
  </div>
  <div class="mainRibbon">
    <input type="text" class="textBoxStyle" placeholder="Enter your username">
    <input type="text" class="textBoxStyle" placeholder="Password">
    <div class="btnLogin">
      <p>Log in</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please show a screenshot of the issue, I cant see it?

Comment: @epoch Appears first time you click the textbox after build

Comment: also, chrome 36, not happening for me...

Comment: I'm not seeing any border at any time. I see a unicode character that does not seem to exist in the font chosen.

Comment: The problem is with the two "textboxes" not with that glyph; the glyph does not appear because the corresponding font is available on my computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved: the issue is that "left-margin" is falling on half-pixel and thus cannot be displayed; I changed "width" from ".main" from "550px" to "560px" and now the left margin displays perfectly;

Thanks to all that suggested to style "outline" to fit my style; it is a good solution only that outline can not have rounded corners as I desire.

Comment: This helped me. Turns out a parent had a margin-left of 1px, causing all children to be on odd pixels. Changing that margin to 2px fixed it for me. (Windows 10, Chrome 51)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why it is doing that but when you add `padding-left:1px` to `.textBoxStyle`, it fixes the problem but not at all times, very wierd.

http://jsfiddle.net/emrfcuu7/3/

ALso I saw that the problem may come from `margin:6% 10% 0% 10%;`, maybe there is not enough space for the border with these margins and you should use pixels margins

**Update**

The real solution: 
You must remove `outline:0` from `.textBoxStyle:focus` and have this :

```
.textBoxStyle:focus{
    border-color:rgba(26,188,156,1);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/emrfcuu7/7/

Comment: I tried this, and it still appears to me to be missing at first

Comment: Try removing all you css rules on `.textBoxStyle` and add them back one by oe to see which is glitchy

Comment: Update, I found the solution to your problem

Comment: @singe31: truly, if I remove "outline:0" the problem disappear but I want my border to be "rgba(26,188,156,1)" not the "default blue".

Comment: @b0s0r0gu I see. Have you tried to use `outline: 1px solid rgba(26,188,156,1)` ? Not sure if this is what you want : http://jsfiddle.net/emrfcuu7/13/

Comment: @singe31: yes, I tried to style the "outline" but it lacks round corners.

Answer (score 0):

give border more than 1px

```
.textBoxStyle{
    position:relative;
    border:2px solid rgba(26,188,156,0);
    border-radius:4px;
    width:80%;
    text-indent:20px;
    box-shadow:none;
    -webkit-box-shadow:none;
    line-height:1.4285;
    -webkit-transition: border-color .25s linear;
    transition: border-color .25s linear;
    margin:6% 10% 0 10%;
    padding-top:6px;
    padding-bottom:6px;
}
```

the issue is not reproducible if margins are removed.

> margin:6% 10% 0 10%;

Answer (score 0):

[**Make use of this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/emrfcuu7/11/)

```
.textBoxStyle:focus{
outline:none;
    border:2px solid rgba(26,188,156,1);
}
```